# Looking to speed up code, Python 3.8/Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The existing Dataframe is roughly 500,000 rows, built as shown

| TITLE_NO | ITEM_TYPE | COMPONENT_NO | COLLECTION_NAME | DATE_ENTERED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 162494 | T | 2 | MASTER RECORDINGS | 5/15/2003 3:50 PM |
| 162494 | G | 1 | MASTER RECORDINGS | 5/15/2003 3:41 PM |

The task - evaluate each unique title_no (which can occur in multiple rows) against the entire dataframe.
The conditions is to select all rows from the dataframe containing each unique title_no when all rows containing that title_no are an ITEM_TYPE of 'G'. If any row in the return for that title_no has a value other than "G" the entire title_no should be disregarded.
The result is a new dataframe containing all the rows found that meet the condition.

So the included example, neither row would be in the resulting dataframe, but If the first row had the item_type changed to "G", BOTH lines would be in the resulting dataframe.

This works, but is slow

---

```
df=pd.read_csv(filelocation)
titles = df.TITLE_NO.unique()
records=[]
for x in titles:
    df_new = df[df['TITLE_NO'] == x]
    if len(df_new)==len(df_new[df_new['ITEM_TYPE']=='G']):
        for x in df_new.values.tolist():
            records.append(x)
xdf = pd.DataFrame(records, columns='TITLE_NO','ITEM_TYPE','COMPONENT_NO','COLLECTION_NAME','DATE_ENTERED'])
```

---

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: instead of: `for x in df_new.values.tolist():
            records.append(x)` try: `records.extend(df_new.values)`

Comment: I would try one of two things, 1. convert the loops into a list comprehension 2. use pyspark instead of pandas

Comment: @Octav - records.extend(df_new.values) appears to be consistently slower than the current loop, at least on a much smaller cut down dataframe except of the original.

Answer (score 0):

I think a groupby apply can save you a lot of time

```
def check_for_G(x):
    if len(x)==len(x[x['ITEM_TYPE']=='G']):
        return x.values.tolist()
    else:
        return None

records = df.groupby('TITLE NO').apply(check_for_G)
```

You might have to do some post processing on `records` before running the next line

```
xdf = pd.DataFrame(records, columns='TITLE_NO','ITEM_TYPE','COMPONENT_NO','COLLECTION_NAME','DATE_ENTERED'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try groupby with boolean indexing. This will avoid any loops, including the loops used with `apply`

```
# groupby and get the unique values of item_type
g = df.groupby('TITLE_NO')['ITEM_TYPE'].unique()
# boolean indexing with isin where the unique values are only 'G'
new_df = df[df['TITLE_NO'].isin(g[g.eq(['G'])].index)]
```

Comment: new_df = df[df['TITLE_NO'].isin(g[g.eq(['G'])].index)]  gives me an error - ValueError: Lengths must be equal